# Why do some git commits have "refs" when I look at them in Tig?

Tags: git, tig

If I run "tig" on a git repo, I see that some commits  have "refs" but some don't. The occurrence of "refs" seems random. I can not find a pattern. Sometimes merge commits have them, but sometimes they don't. Sometimes regular commits have them, but sometimes they don't.

So here is a merge that does not have "refs":

```
  commit 632647ebce1bf9c3f125635706a4d0ea34930837
  Merge: c98c7c3 399d871
  Author:     Tommmy
  AuthorDate: Tue Mar 8 17:01:34 2016 -0500
  Commit:     Tommy
  CommitDate: Tue Mar 8 17:01:34 2016 -0500
```

Here is a merge commit with "refs":

```
  commit 2f5d7ba2e6da74e612702267fecd5c55a3709bd2
  Refs: {origin/fogbugz-2159}
  Merge: 0294a42 4a4e27d
  Author:     Tommy
  AuthorDate: Wed Feb 24 10:00:27 2016 -0500
  Commit:     Tommy
  CommitDate: Wed Feb 24 10:00:27 2016 -0500
```

And likewise, with commits that are not merge commits, some have "refs" and some do not. What determines which has "refs"?

Comment: And the refs don't correspond to branch names?

Comment: They are branch names. But which branch names? Some tig entries list 2 "refs", others list 1, whereas most list 0. Why? If they were related to merges then this would make sense, but there seems to be no pattern that I can see.

Comment: A Git branch is just a pointer to a specific commit.

Comment: I know. But my question is why "refs" shows up in some log entries and not others.

Comment: Because most commits in a Git repo don't correspond to refs.

Comment: But which ones do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Refs` line contains the names of local and remote branches, tags, as well as the output of `git describe` unless the commit has been tagged.

Formatting of the refs can be configured via `reference-format`:

- `[]` are used for local branches, e.g. `[master]`
- `{}` are used for remotes, eg. `{origin/master}`
- `<>` are used for tags, e.g. `<v1.1.0>`

Comment: About "The Refs line contains the names of local and remote branches, tags" -- I know that, the question I am asking is why do some commits have a "refs" line and some don't. I'm unable to see any pattern in which commits have a "refs" line and which don't.

Comment: What version of tig are you using?

Comment: I am using version 2.1.1

Comment: @lorm This is likely a bug. To verify please check if the commits with no "Refs" line has a lot of branches/remotes/tags. All ref names matching a commit are rendered into a buffer and if all can not fit no line is shown (see https://github.com/jonas/tig/blob/master/src/pager.c#L61). If your repo does not have any tags the "Refs" line will also only show for commits with branches/remotes/tags